# Как сделать скрипт прогноза погоды с геолокацией?

Tags: геолокация

Пробовал через geolocation api от yahoo, но там скрипт спрашивает у пользователя о местоположении и только потом срабатывает, а мне надо чтобы сразу при входе на сайт показывал погоду

Comment: @reddyk, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, какой зяык используете, каким образом взаимодействуете с сервисом, откуда берете IP и т. д.

Comment: Вроде все понятно, нужен информер погоды с геолокацией, пробовал через yahoo api, но там прям в браузере требует разрешения на определения местоположения, а мне надо чтобы сразу

Comment: http://openweathermap.org/API  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363052/best-weather-apis-free-for-commercial-use

Answer (score 2):

Демка и рабочий скрипт на ajax и maxmind [информера с определением города по ip](http://masterpro.ws/snova-maxmind-snova-pogodnye-informery-i-snova-ajax) здесь по ссылке, можно просто открыть страничку и забрать.